# In how many ways can a dating service match each of six females one of eight males?

Tags: statistics, combinations

The question reads:

A dating service has the names of six females and eight males who seek matches. In how many ways can the service match each female with one male?

Using the multiplication principle, I thought that the answer should just be $6\times8 = 48$. But I've been told that is the wrong answer, I can't work out how to do this using combinations as the are two types of object present.

I know this will seem straightforward to someone else, but I really don't know how to wrap my head around it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The new title isn't much better.

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry, I wasn't sure what to put as a title really without just putting the whole question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ordered selection.

Arrange the females in some order, say alphabetically.  There are eight ways of matching a male to the first woman on the list. This leaves seven men available for the dating service to match to the second woman on the list.  Continuing to match the $9 - k$ available men to the $k$th woman on the list yields
$$8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{2 \cdot 1} = \frac{8!}{2!} = P(8, 6)$$
possible assignments of dates to the women on the list.

Answer (score 1):

From $8$ male $6$ can be selected so ${8\choose 6}$ then each female can be selected for each male. Can you see how to proceed further with normal multiplication theorem

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking about it in the right way :)